# Cannot convert string into float in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to convert a string (such as 10.99) into a float in a for loop, and I can't figure out a way to do it with the data I've scraped from a website. I need to divide the output by another float (also in the for loop). The below is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
import re

test_data = ['\n\t\t\t\t£10.00 per 100ML', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.40 per EACH', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.54 per EACH', '\n\t\t\t\t£1.33 per EACH']
price_data = [100, 10.99, 20.99, 25.25, 30, 35, 40, 54, 3]

for items in zip(test_data, price_data):
    characters = re.sub("\[p].*$|[^\d\.]", "", items[0])
    price_per_unit = characters[0:5]

    price = items[1]

    number_of_units = price / float(price_per_unit)
```

I then get the error:

```
    number_of_units = price / float(price_per_unit)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

What's the best way to turn price_per_unit into a float, and calculate number_of_units??

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT: Working solution below for anyone else who's interested

```
import re

test_data = ['\n\t\t\t\t£10.00 per 100ML', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.40 per EACH', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.54 per EACH', '\n\t\t\t\t£1.33 per EACH']
price_data = [100, 10.99, 20.99, 25.25, 30, 35, 40, 54, 3]

for items in zip(test_data, price_data):
    price = items[1]

    characters = re.sub("\[p].*$|[^\d\.]", "", items[0])
    price_per_unit = characters[0:5]
    if price_per_unit.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
        price_per_unit_formatted = float(price_per_unit)
        number_of_units = price / price_per_unit_formatted
    else:
        price_per_unit = None
        number_of_units = None
```

Comment: You need to cast *both* operands into floats to be compatible.

Comment: Your ```re.sub()``` part is not working good, It doesn't return any data. I don't get what were you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not from the `float()` function. When the code parses the `test_data`, the `'\xa0'` will return an empty string `''`, this empty string cannot be converted to float point value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As **Bill** said, your problem is due to the fact that some of `price_per_unit` are `''`.
a simple wrap around this issue is making sure that the `price_per_unit` is indeed a number for instance in the following way:

```
if price_per_unit.replace('.','',1).isdigit():
      number_of_units = price / float(price_per_unit)
```

This will ignore those `''` and still maintain its functionality

Comment: Super helpful thank you @David S! I've taken your suggestion and added it to my code, working perfectly:

Answer (score 1):

if I understand what you're asking for:

```
number_of_units=[]
for items in zip(test_data, price_data):
  if (items[0]!='\xa0'):
    characters = re.sub("\[p].*$|[^\d\.]", "", items[0])
    price_per_unit = characters[0:5]

    price = items[1]

    number_of_units.append(price / float(price_per_unit))
  else:
    number_of_units.append(1)

number_of_units #[10.0, 1, 52.474999999999994, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100.0, 2.255639097744361]
```

considered '\xa0' elements as 1 indivisible unit.

Using a list to store all the values generated in the loop, with your code you would store only the last.

Answer (score 1):

the \xa0 is becoming a empty string, you should handle it

```
import re

test_data = ['\n\t\t\t\t£10.00 per 100ML', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.40 per EACH', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.54 per EACH', '\n\t\t\t\t£1.33 per EACH']
price_data = [100, 10.99, 20.99, 25.25, 30, 35, 40, 54, 3]

for items in zip(test_data, price_data):

    characters = re.sub("\[p].*$|[^\d\.]", "", items[0])

    price_per_unit = characters[:5]
    if price_per_unit == '':
      print('empty')
      break
    price = items[1]

    number_of_units = price/ float(price_per_unit)
    print(number_of_units)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing SUBSTR of Test_Data where string like '\xa0' exists then it's giving an empty string in your price_per_unit variable. To avoid this you can replace it with '1' as replacing with '0' would give an error of division by zero.

```
    import re

test_data = ['\n\t\t\t\t£10.00 per 100ML', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.40 per EACH', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\n\t\t\t\t£0.54 per EACH', '\n\t\t\t\t£1.33 per EACH']
price_data = [100, 10.99, 20.99, 25.25, 30, 35, 40, 54, 3]

for items in zip(test_data, price_data):
    characters = re.sub("\[p].*$|[^\d\.]", "", items[0])
    price_per_unit = characters[0:5]


    price = items[1]

    if price_per_unit == '':
      price_per_unit = '1'
    else:
      price_per_unit

    print('---------')
    number_of_units = price / float(price_per_unit)
    print(number_of_units)
```

For better understanding of errors it's better to print the variable when you get an error. That's how I came to know why this issue was occurring.